# How using size_t as a parameter works

Tags: c++, hashtable, size-t

So I am making my first attempt in making a hash table and am completely stumped as to what to do for my constructors?

```
class HashTable {
   typedef vector <list<HashNode> > Table;
   Table *table; // size of table is stored in the Table data structure
   size_t num;   // number of entries in the HashTable;
}
```

this is the class I'm trying to make constructors for and I have been given.

```
public:
   HashTable();       // constructor, initializes table of size 1;
   HashTable(size_t num); // constructor, requires size of table as arg
```

I don't really understand as to what am supposed to do. So first I'm to initialize the size of the `table` to 1. Which since I'm using a vector, I'm assuming I'm to use the `reserve` function? So I went ahead and got this:

```
this->table->resize(num);
```

which compiled fine and I had no issue with and I think is correct. The second constructor is where I had an issue understanding, mainly due to the use of `size_t`. By my understanding here is where I set the size of the table to `size_t`? But what is `size_t` supposed to be? I think its a data type but why would I set the `Hashtable` size to a datatype? Unless I'm missing something obvious here I can't see.

Comment: It is possible you are looking for the under-taught and very-important [Member Initiallizer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). Eg `HashTable::HashTable(size_t size): table(new Table(size)), num(0) {}`.

Comment: Note: `Table *table` borders on being an incredibly stupid thing to do. The entire point of `std::vector` is to remove the burden of manual memory management from the programmer. Dynamically allocating a `vector` thrusts this responsibility back onto them, defeating the point. You almost never want to dynamically allocate a `vector`. I don't think I ever have.

Comment: In addition to having to `delete` the `vector` at some point, one bit of nastiness this pointer drops in your lap is the [Rules of Three and Five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). `vector` observes the Rule of Five for you, allowing your structures to let `vector` do the dirty work and observe the Rule of Zero--do nothing. With a pointer to a `vector`, you're now responsible for making certain that the `vector` is properly handled when `HashTable` is copied, moved, or assigned.

Comment: @user4581301 yea i dont really understand why they're making us use Table *table, but for this work i'm to use the supplied headers to make the code, main reason why im struggling tbh, trying to make sense of something I wouldnt do myself when implementing and figuring why and how to code it

Comment: Your instructor has probably set this up to teach you a difficult lesson. The alternative is the instructor should not be allowed to teach C++. Pray for the first and get yourself some alternate learning materials in case they're the second.

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) and [`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize). I suspect you would prefer the second for this case, but you're better off constructing the `vector` with the correct size and save yourself the trouble of resizing later.

Comment: Note: I'm not answering this formally because I don't think I can without spoiling the bulk of the assignment.

Comment: @user4581301 so i tried again and think i have a solution that compiles at least. updated post with new try. since size-t is data type, in parameter rather than just asking for size-t, i asked for the field num, using that to resize the vector

Comment: Are you new to the idea of function parameters? `Hashtable(size_t num);` declares a function, the constructor, with one parameter whose type is `size_t` and whose name is `num`. You could look for tutorials or information about how function parameters work for standalone functions; and once you understand it, come back to this problem